# Differences when opening sockets with Python and Java

Tags: java, python, sockets

I am running into a really weird problem when opening and closing multiple
sequential connections to the same host using Java.

I am trying to run a `for` cycle to open a tcp socket, send some data, receive a
response and close the connection. After the third iteration of this cycle, it
stops working. Opening and writing to the socket still works, but not the read.

I first assumed this was a problem with my remote host, but I wrote small python
script to debug this, and it works fine, the script easily executes my `for`
cycle for more than 50 iterations and the remote host always replies as
expected.

Is there anything different in the way python opens and closes sockets when
compared with the way Java does it? How can I debug this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

here's the code I am using in both cases:

Python:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.send(command)
    data = s.recv(1024)
    data = data[2:]
    print 'Received', "--->%s<--" % data.decode()
```

Java

```
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9998);

        OutputStream bos = socket.getOutputStream();
        InputStream bis = socket.getInputStream();

        byte[] raw = "XX0000NC".getBytes();
        raw[0] = 0x0;
        raw[1] = 0x6;

        bos.write(raw);
        bos.flush();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int readCount = bis.read(buffer);

        System.out.println(new String(Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 2, readCount)));

        socket.shutdownOutput();
        socket.shutdownInput();
        socket.close();
    }
```

Comment: Both python and Java map fairly straight to the underlying socket  functions. **Please post the code** you're having problems with.

Comment: Try doing a `shutdown` before a `close`. That will be more TCP friendly.

Comment: @rodrigo thanks. That didn't change anything though.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing the value of `command` used in the Python code. Maybe you are sending different commands?

The only other difference I can see is that in Python you use `socket.send' while in java you use`OutputStream.write`:

The different behavior happens when there is not enough buffer space to write all the data:

- `send` sends only the amount of data it can send without blocking and returns the number of bytes sent. If no bytes can be send, then it blocks.
- `write` blocks until all the bytes are sent.

Admittedly, I find this unlikely because you are sending a very short command...

You can test easily for this event changing your Python code to:

```
for i in range(0, 10):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    sent = s.send(command)
    if sent != len(command):
        print 'Some bytes not sent!!!\n'
    data = s.recv(1024)
    data = data[2:]
    print 'Received', "--->%s<--" % data.decode()
```